# Is there a way to differentiate whether I am currently in a windows or linux container in dockerfile itself?

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run an asp.net core app in docker container, for which I have built the required Dockerfile.
I have also integrated unit tests and code coverage within the Dockerfile for the same.

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Demo.API/Demo.API.csproj Demo.API/
RUN dotnet restore Demo.API/Demo.API.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Demo.API
RUN dotnet build Demo.API.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build as unittest
WORKDIR /src
COPY Demo.UnitTests/Demo.UnitTests.csproj Demo.UnitTests/
RUN dotnet restore Demo.UnitTests/Demo.UnitTests.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Demo.UnitTests
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
RUN find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 unix2dos
RUN dotnet test --verbosity=normal --results-directory /TestResults/ 
--logger "trx;LogFileName=test_results.xml" /p:CollectCoverage=true
/p:Exclude="[xunit*]*" /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover 
/p:CoverletOutput='reports/coverage/clover.xml' Demo.UnitTests.csproj

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish Demo.API.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Demo.API.dll"]
```

Here in this part :

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
RUN find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 unix2dos
RUN dotnet test --verbosity=normal --results-directory /TestResults/ 
--logger "trx;LogFileName=test_results.xml" /p:CollectCoverage=true
/p:Exclude="[xunit*]*" /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover 
/p:CoverletOutput='reports/coverage/clover.xml' Demo.UnitTests.csproj
```

, in the second line I am trying to convert all my text files to dos format.

This is because these files have CarriageReturnLinFeed (/r/n) , which get converted to just having LineFeed(/n), because Linux only uses LineFeed (/n).
I am forcefully reconverting them back to have CarriageReturnLinFeed (/r/n) by using unix2dos.

This is very essential because some of the unit tests use CarriageReturnLinFeed (/r/n) as basis of tests, and would otherwise Fail the tests if it gets just LineFeed.

But in order to run

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
```

, I have to be in a Linux container.
But I want to be able to do the same in a windows container too.

Is there a way to differentiate whether I am currently running the dockerfile in a Linux or windows container and write some kind of if statement within the dockerfile itself and conditionally run or not run the apt-get statement ?

Comment: You can find more information related to building images for different OS using the same docker file here:

1. https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1020

2. https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/

Thanks

Comment: You can do it via switching the running docker like Switch to Window's Container or Switch to Linus Container. Get more information here https://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2017/12/28/multi-platform-docker-images/

https://docs.docker.com/engine/faq/

Thanks